# Identifying UI hang issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

Is there any tool which gives you the view of current execution of you code? I need this because my WPF application's UI is hanging without any notification/exceptions. I am not able to debug the issue. System stays Idle and every time I have to kill the process explicitly. Any suggestions. FYI.. many third party tools are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use windbg to fully investigate all aspects of a process. While there is a learning curve involved, in my opinion, becoming familiar with this tool is vital for a developer. To get started get a full memory dump of your running process via task manager & download & install [debugging tools for windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx). Once you've this done take a look at some tutorials & I'll try and help if you post a comment back

Comment: it keeps on saying "Symbol file could not be found"

Comment: have you specified your symbol path ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you have tested already and maybe I answer is invalid but:

Have you tried to use the pause function in Visual Studio. It pauses all threads of your application and you can see per Thread where it is paused. You can also step through each Thread to find possible issues.

Some issues I had in the past:

- Too much actions where executed immediately from the UI Thread

  - Dispatch big chunk of work to background threads using the `BackgroundWorker`
- Incorrect locking model so that the UI thread is not able to gather the information it wants

  - Make sure data in the ViewModel cannot be changed by background threads without locking properties.

Some interesting links to read about WPF and MultiThreading:

- [WPF Fundamentals - Threading Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)
- [Debugging locks and deadlocks](http://www.microframework.nl/2009/02/23/debugging-locks-and-deadlocks/)

Hopefully this helps you a bit

Comment: I just dumped the process and tried debugging the dump in visual studio and found it's a deadlock situation!!

Comment: making use of the `lock` keywork can help you out preventing deadlocks

Comment: Every time I pause the debugger it takes me to lock(obj) statement

Comment: - Are there more threads which can lock the `obj` object?
- Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing Memory/CPU Consuming tasks using the  main thread the UI will become Idle even without any exceptions.To solve this issue use a BackgroudWorker/a Separate thread to do the time consuming operations.So that UI will not freeze.